# Is there something wrong that I'm missing with this code?

Tags: jquery

There's something wrong with this code, but I'm not experienced enough to be able to figure it out.  Hoping for some help.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactform').submit(function(){

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
        $('#message').hide();

          $('#submit')
            .attr('disabled','disabled');
     if($('#process').val()=='1'){
        $.post(action, $('#contactform').serialize(),
            function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();
                                                                      });
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');

            }
        );
    else {
        $.post(action, $('#contactform').serialize(),
        function(data){
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();
                                                                      });
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                if(data.match('success') !== null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
            }
        );

        });

        return false;
        });
    });

});
```

Thank you!!!  Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="message"></div>

    <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

    <fieldset>

    <input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="1">

    <label for="name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" />

    <br />
    <label for="email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />

    <br />
    <label for="phone">Phone<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" size="30" value="" />

    <br />
    <label for="comments">Comments<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="15" id="comments" style="width: 350px;"></textarea>

    <br />
    <label>Are you human?<span class="required">*</span></label>

    <label class="accesskey" for="verify">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 + 1 =</label>
    <input class="accesskey" name="verify" id="verify" size="4" value="" style="width: 30px;" /><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

    </fieldset>

    </form>
</div><!--end contact-->
```

Comment: it'd help if you could post a link to a jsfiddle.net example, or post the html document that you're using this jquery snippet with.

Comment: or tell us what the 'something' is thats wrong with it? an error message perhaps?

Comment: I added the html, but I really feel like its just a syntax error...missing } or misplaced ;

Comment: If I knew what the "something" was, I wouldn't be here right now...

Comment: Sorry, but it's very likely that this question will be closed. You did not even tell us what this code is supposed to do exactly. Also, even if you are not experienced, showing some effort would be welcome. Like asking how to debug the code instead of asking other people to do your job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `}` before `else {` and the end of the `else` before `return false` should be `}`, not `});`  At least that's one thing.

There is also a disturbing lack of comments.

```
} else {  // <= HERE add }
    $.post(action, $('#contactform').serialize(),
    function(data){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();
                                                                  });
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') !== null) $('#contactform').slideUp('slow');
        }
    );

} // <= HERE remove );

return false;
```

Comment: thank you so much Jeff!  that is extremely helpful!  everyone else:  was that so hard???